# Jquery submit on enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
<div class="search">
    <input type="text" id="tbWasSearch" value="Search here..." class="project" onclick="this.value=''"/>
    <input type="button" id="tbWasSeachButton" class="tbWasSeachButton" onclick="searchWas();" />
</div>

    function searchWas() {
        var txt = $("#tbWasSearch").val();
        if (txt != "") {
            var url = "http://eiff/server.pt?=" + txt;
            window.open(url);
            $("#tbWasSearch").val('');
        }
    }
```

I want that once i put text in tbWasSearch and press enter, the text entered with inoke 
searchWas(); 
Should be the same mechanism as when i put text and click the search button

How can this be done?

Comment: Why don't you use `form` tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [keyuy](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event:

```
var reload = function(e) { 
   if (e.keyCode == '13')
      searchWas();
};

$('#tbWasSearch').keyup(reload);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery you can write something like this

```
$("#tbWasSearch").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#tbWasSeachButton").click();
    }
});
```

where 13 is the keyCode for the return key

Answer (score 0):

also , if you use form tag you can use :

```
$('form:first').submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You use form something like this..

<script>
function searchWas() {
    var txt = $("#tbWasSearch").val();
    if (txt != "") {
        var url = "http://eiff/server.pt?=" + txt;
        window.open(url);
        $("#tbWasSearch").val('');
    }
}
</script>

<form action="javascript:searchWas();">
<div class="search">
<input type="text" id="tbWasSearch" value="Search here..." class="project" onclick="this.value=''"/>
<input type="button" id="tbWasSeachButton" class="tbWasSeachButton" />
</div>
</form>
```